# Finding the generating set of a $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega=(0,1]$.

Let $\beta$ be the Borel $\sigma-$algebra generated by open sets in $\Omega$.
Now,$\tilde\beta$={$B\subset\Omega :B\in\beta$ and is either disjoint from$(\frac{1}{2},1]$ or contains $(\frac{1}{2},1]$}.

$\tilde{\beta}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra on $\Omega=(0,1]$.This is easy to prove.

I need to prove $\tilde{\beta}$=$\sigma \{\mathbf{C}$=collection of all intervals contained in $(0.\frac{1}{2}]\}$.

One,side should be easy.
Now,elements of $\mathbf{C}$ are  disjoint from $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ and hence are in $\tilde{\beta}$.

Thus,$\sigma(\mathbf{C})\subset\tilde{\beta}$.I am not able to prove the other way around.

Comment: i took the question from the book Measure and Probability V.S.Sunder,Problem no 1.2.14,pg 5,I think the definition of  $\mathbf{C}$ should have $(0, \frac{1}{2}]$ instead of $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ which is given in the book,i have posted the question accordingly.The original question in the book had .$(0,\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: For $A \in \tilde{\beta}$, consider $A_1 = A \cap (0,1/2]$ and $A_2 = A \cap (1/2,1]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer so $A=A_1 \cup A_2$ where $ A_1 $ is in $\tilde{\beta}$ and i can conclude that $A_2$ is also in $\tilde{\beta}$ since both$A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint and their union is $A$.I  don't see how it is helping i am not able  connect $A_1$ or $A_2$ with  $\sigma({\mathbf{C}})$ since $\mathbf{C}$ is composed of intervals

Comment: If you can show that $A_1 \in \sigma(C)$ and $A_2 \in \sigma(C)$, you're through. Why is $A_1 \in \sigma(C)$? And why $A_2 \in \sigma(C)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer i'm sorry maybe i am missing something very obvious but $A_1$ is contained in $(0,\frac{1}{2}]$  so it can be written as a union of intervals all of which are from $\mathbf{C}$ but this union needn't be countable....ri8 so it wont fall in the sigma-algebra?

Comment: Perhaps this reveals it: You can view $C$ as a family in $\mathfrak{P}\bigl((0,1/2]\bigr)$. What is $\sigma_{(0,1/2]}(C)$, the $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathfrak{P}\bigl((0,1/2]\bigr)$ generated by $C$?